# Sass nested maps - issue with Sassmeister?

Tags: css, sass

According to [this article](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/so-you-want-to-play-with-list-maps):

```
$input-disabled-color:#333;

$input: (
  disabled (
    background lighten($input-disabled-color, 75%),
    border lighten($input-disabled-color, 50%),
    text lighten($input-disabled-color, 50%)
  )
);

input[disabled] {
  background-color: map-get-z($input, disabled, background);
  border-color: map-get-z($input, disabled, border);
  color: map-get-z($input, disabled, text);
}
```

should render to:

```
input[disabled] {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-color: #b3b3b3;
  color: #b3b3b3; 
}
```

Yet, on [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com) it renders as

```
input[disabled] {
   background-color: map-get-z(disabled background #f2f2f2, border #b3b3b3, text #b3b3b3,  disabled, background);
   border-color: map-get-z(disabled background #f2f2f2, border #b3b3b3, text #b3b3b3, disabled, border);
   color: map-get-z(disabled background #f2f2f2, border #b3b3b3, text #b3b3b3, disabled, text);
```

}

In my original question I assumed I did it wrong, but it seems the actual code from this article is either incorrect, or Sassmeister doesn't do map-get-z.

Any thoughts on which it is?

Comment: Your question is *still* a duplicate.  The function you're trying to use is not a native Sass function.  It comes from a 3rd party library, which was conveniently linked to in the article you're following.

Comment: ugh.  I missed that part completely.  My apologies.